# Android Studio - Android Emulator Won't Boot

Tags: android, android-studio, emulation

I just downloaded and installed Android Studio (v 2.3.3), and am starting to teach myself programming for Android by following Google's tutorials. (I finished the Java MOOC courses offered by University of Helsinki a little while ago). However, I can't seem to get the emulator working (following the instructions [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/running-app.html)). I chose the Nexus 5x (same as my phone), but it seems to be frozen on the boot screen. The animation has stopped.

This is what it looks like

[image: [1]]
I've tried deleting the emulator and recreating it again, but that didn't change it. I can't close or stop the emulator. I can't even kill it with the Task Manager (I'm on Windows 10). None of the buttons next to the boot screen do anything, except the three dots on the bottom, which open up the Extended Controls. The Android Virtual Device Manager won't let me start, stop, or delete it. The only way I was able to remove it and create a new one was to kill it by restarting my computer.

It's a fresh installation, and I'm extremely new to Android development, so I have no idea what to try next.

Comment: The first boot is always the longest. It's super slow if using AMD cpu

Comment: Pretty sure it's beyond that. The animation (gradient effect across the "android" letters) is stuck, and it literally hasn't done anything in the three hours it's been "booting."

Also, I have an Intel Core2Quad 9400.

Comment: Did you install the intel HAXM drivers?

Comment: Yes, it wouldn't let me start it without them. However, I went to Intel's site, and it looks like the drivers that Android Studio installed weren't the latest drivers. I installed the latest ones (6.1.2), and... nothing. Same issue - frozen android animation on boot screen, can't kill it without restarting computer.

Comment: I also just tried to use a different virtual device - I chose a 2.7 QVGA, using API 22 (Lollipop). Same result.

Comment: Hmm. Personally, I use Genymotion even though there's supposed performance improvements in the builtin emulator